# How to find out that whether ComboBox items are shown or not in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` and an `ImageView` as below , my goal is to push the `ImageView` lower when user clicks on the `ComboBox` because `ComboBox` items go over the `ImageView` and hide it. But the `ImageView` must be visible. Here is a picture of a [part of my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui6ep.jpg).

Here is part of my code:

```
        yourTeamFormation.setCellFactory((Object lv) -> {
        ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                setText(item);
            }
        };
        cell.hoverProperty().addListener((obs, wasHovered, isNowHovered) -> {
            if (cell.isEmpty()) {
                yFormationDis.setImage(null);
            } else {
                yFormationDis.setImage(getImage(cell.getItem()));
                yFormationDis.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
            }
        });
        return cell ;
    });
    yourTeamFormation.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener <String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            if(yFormationDis.getLayoutY() == 148)
                yFormationDis.relocate(yFormationDis.getLayoutX() ,67);
            setFormation.setOpacity(100);
            try {
                in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("playerFormation.txt"));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String temp = newValue + "%";
            temp = temp.trim();
            while (in.hasNext()){
                String temp2 = in.next();

                if(temp2.contains("%")){
                    if(temp.equals(temp2)){
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int  i = 0; i < XYNow.length ; i++){
                XYNow[i] = Double.parseDouble(in.next());
            }
            YourFormation = newValue;
        }
    });
    yourTeamFormation.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        setFormation.setOpacity(0);
        if(yFormationDis.getLayoutY() == 67)
            yFormationDis.setLayoutY(148);
    });
```

It is almost fine, but there is a big bug: when the user clicks on the `ComboBox` the `ImageView` will be pushed lower, but if user doesn't change the value of `ComboBox` and closes it (hides `ComboBox` items) the `ImageView` won't turn back to its first place, because `ComboBox` value doesn't change. So is there any way to resolve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking, but can't you just use `yourTeamFormation.showingProperty().addListener(...)`?

Comment: Thanks , that was what i want.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem

Comment: you know i have got what i wanted to know from dear James_D comment.